# Editing Transaction data with checkout.js

Tags: paypal

With the default checkout.js express checkout code in place - how can I edit the transaction details on the fly? We do select the product via a radio button - product A, product B, product C - each with a different name and different price. I somehow need to edit the transaction details to pass in the shipping details, name, email etc. pass that onto PayPal along with the selected products details. 
After that I want to redirect the user to a thank you page and record the details of the purchase. Does anyone know how and if this is possible?

Thank you!

```
paypal.Button.render({
    env: 'sandbox',
    client: {
        sandbox:    'XXXXXXXXXX',
        production: 'XXXXXXXXXX'
    },
    commit: true,
    payment: function() {
        return paypal.rest.payment.create(this.props.env, this.props.client, {
            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: { total: 0.99, currency: 'EUR' }
                }
            ]
        });
    },
    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
    },
}, '#paypal-button-container');
```